# Method to forecast correlate univariate time-series (with trend, seasonality) via regression

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, python, linear

I have two univariate time-series with seasonality and trend--dt1 and dt2. I believe that dt1 and dt2 are strongly correlated, both through a few statistical test (see below) and that in my field dt2 is a proxy for dt1.

**Linear Regression Research**

Plot (shows seasonality and trend--which was expected)
[image: Plot]

Pearson correlation = .815
Scatter plot showing correlation and checked residuals for OLS
[image]

[image]

**Goal/Question**

Ultimately I want to use dt1 off dt2.I don't actually need to forecast dt2 or make predictions about it, since it is a leading indicator and I actually can collect that data before dt1 is available.

Since I don't need to actually predict/forecast dt1 on it's own--I don't think (and I can be completely wrong) ARIMA or lagged/autoregressive studies--I am using dt2 to forecast it.

**Is a Linear Regression the best starting point (even with dt1 having obvious season/trend time components)--should I be looking into a ARIMAX or another tool?**